# How can I limit the number of inputs while using istringstream for parsing (C++)

Tags: c++

I should get multiples lines of input from cin and I need to take only 2 integers for each lines.

I used `while(getline(cin, input))` and `istringstream iss(input)` to handle errors.

and I used the return value of iss >> d (double type variable), iss >> s (string type variable)

to handle the error like ( 1 2 extrainput ; that is, integer integer string)

because I thought that there is no other case that input value is neither double nor string

Is there any other elegant way to limit the number of inputs for each line?

(If there are more than 3 input values, it should be considered as error case)

Comment: No there is no elegant way. The way to do this is to forget about streams and instead *analyse* the input string character by character to see if it matches your expectations.

Comment: @john thank you for your replying!

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way I know is just to wrap it in `operator>>` with a custom type.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, int_pair& pair) {
    std::string tempstring;
    if (!std::getline(stream, tempstring)) return stream;
    std::stringstream line(tempstring);
    int_pair temppair; //temp so that invalid end of line doesn't modify parameter
    line >> temppair.first;
    line >> temppair.second;
    std::getline(line, tempstring);
    if (!tempstring.empty()) stream.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    pair = temppair;
    return stream;
}
```

Then usage becomes elegant

```
int main(){
    int_pair one_pair;
    std::cin >> one_pair;
    std::cout << one_pair;
    
    std::vector<int_pair> vector;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int_pair>(std::cin), {}, std::back_inserter(vector));
    std::copy(vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int_pair>(std::cout));
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ceb5b7922ac03b5

(I have a bug somewhere, the second call to `getline` on the input is failing and I don't know why, but the point is valid regardless)